# Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'SKView'

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have two View Controllers, one is GameViewController (this one is created by xcode when I start a new game project) and MenuViewController. This last one presents the user with a button 'start game.' When the button is pressed, the GameViewController view should be presented. However, the program crashes instead with the message in the title.

In 'MenuViewController' I have

```
func startGameButtonAction(sender:UIButton!) {

        let gameViewController = GameViewController()
        self.presentViewController(gameViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

In 'GameViewController' I have

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        let skView = self.view as! SKView // crash occurs here
 }
```

I need the skView to be an SKView because GameViewController presents an SKScene.

Answer (score 4):

If you user storyboard, you can set View's custom class to SKView, like this:

[image]

then:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. I've suggested an edit to move the images inline so they're easier to view. As it's much harder for someone to transcribe code from an image, could you also please add the code directly to your post (edit your post to do so, then highlight the code and click the code block button on the toolbar to format it properly).

Answer (score 1):

It's because `self.view` isn't an `SKView`. If you inspect the view in Interface Builder you'll see that it's probably just a generic `UIView`.

Additionally you can set a breakpoint on the line that crashes and then at run time you can print out `self.view` to confirm what class it is.

Comment: GameViewController is an SKView in the view interface builder. Additionally, if I remove MenuViewController from the picture and use only GameViewController, everything works just fine.

Comment: You are right, `self.view` is a `UIView`. How would you go about fixing this? As I mentioned, I need to force `self.view` to be of type `SKView` in order to present an `SKScene`. Also, why is it that everything runs smoothly if I avoid using `MenuViewController` and `presentViewController`?

Comment: This is wrong: let gameViewController = GameViewController(). If you use storyboard, you should either present the controller via segue, or properly instantiate the controller from code with identifier. Pure init won't instantiate the controller.