# Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'SKView' (removed Storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skview

I'm working for the first time with SpriteKit and I have an issue at app launch:

> Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x2038a8848) to 'SKView' (0x2039f2658).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003621/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uiview-to-skview) makes clear that you have to set the `GameViewController`'s `view` custom class to `SKView` and explain how to do it using Storyboard. The problem is that I'm trying to do it programmatically, as i removed the Storyboard, and I have no idea how to do it. As I'm used to UIKit, this has never gave me issues of any kind.

So, in `AppDelegate` i say:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.rootViewController = GameViewController()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.window = window
    return true
}
```

In `GameViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    gameScene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)
    gameScene!.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    gameScene!.gameSceneDelegate = self
    
    show(gameScene!, animated: true)
    
}
```

All I get is the up above error when i try do downcast the VC `view` as a `SKView`.
Can anybody shine a light on how to launch the app programmatically under these conditions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where your mistake is:

```
let skView = view as! SKView
```

You are assuming that `self.view` is an instance of `SKView`, but it isn't. It's a `UIView`, just like how in the storyboard, the root view by default has the class `UIView`.

You should instead do:

```
let skView = SKView()
view = skView
```

To set the root view to an instance of `SKView`.

Comment: Worked, had to set the frame because setting .zero gave me a blank screen tho.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The view controllers's view in storyboard has a `SKView` class name being set there , when you delete it you roll to usual vc's view so add this to your `GameViewController`

```
override func loadView() {
    self.view = SKView() 
}
```

> Tip : `loadView` is where you should init the view controller's view when there is no associated storyboard/xib